# onClick function is causing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }" error

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a problem, I'm trying to dynamically add some html via javascript, and the html has a js function that's supposed to trigger when it's clicked, but I keep getting this error no matter what I do `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }` Has anyone had this problem before?

```
$("#addVehicle").click(function () {
    vehicleQueue += '<li class="ui-state-default">' + $("#years option:selected").text() + ' - ' + $("#make option:selected").text() + ' - ' + $("#model option:selected").text() + ' - ' + $("#trim option:selected").text() + '<span><img onclick="javascript:alert("Hola");" class="removeVehicle" width="25px" src="http://haveagreatholiday.com/img/popup-closeButton.png"></span></li>';

    $("#vehicleQueue").html('<ul id="sortable">' + vehicleQueue + '</ul>');
    vehicleJson.push({
        vehicleCount: vehicleCount,
        vehicleYear: $("#years option:selected").text(),
        vehicleMake: $("#make option:selected").text(),
        vehicleModel: $("#model option:selected").text(),
        vehicleTrim: $("#trim option:selected").text()
    });
    vehicleCount++;
    });
```

This is my head:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="functions.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<style>
  #sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 97%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.2em; height: 18px; }
  #sortable li span {width: 16px;height: 17px;display: block;text-decoration: none;position: absolute;right: 18px;top: 3px;}
</style>

</head>
```

Comment: share your complete script tag, there is an syntactical error in your script

Comment: @ArunPJohny I added the whole script.

Comment: This portion looks fine, check in your browser console where the error is coming from (line). The error is coming from somewhere else

Comment: @ArunPJohny The browser console is giving the error message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }.

Comment: along with the message it will show the filename and line number

Comment: @ArunPJohny It has the url to the page then it says :/2,  but the only thing that's on the second line is my <head> tag.

Comment: is there any `<script>` element in the head if it is there share that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30451/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-william-l)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your onclick event handler has string escape problems, escape is as

```
onclick="alert(\'Hola\');"
```

Comment: This was so unguessable!